# Is there any significant loss of cooling efficiency to wrap the both sunction line and liquid line together using one single insulator?

Tags: air-conditioning, heat-pump

The installation of a split-type air-conditioner wraps both sunction line and liquid line together using one single insulation, instead of wraping each line separately.  Is there any **significant** loss of cooling efficiency to do so?

[image]

[EDIT1: Looks like that I mixed up the pipes and now corrected them.]

[EDIT2: This type of installation is very common in my city and they even wrap the electric wires inside the insulator too.]

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this done. I thought the return suction line was supposed to be cold to help cool the compressor. There is no need to wrap the high pressure liquid line at all.

Comment: This type of installation is very common in my city and they even wrap the electric wires inside the insulator too.